# How to search for document with specific url pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a elastic search index with field url with following mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "url": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "aggregation": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 8191
                    },
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 8191,
                        "normalizer": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write search query to fetch docs which match /A/*/B/* but not any of its child url's lime /A/*/B/*/C

Query that I have tried to match /A/*/B/* is

```
_search?q=url:\\/A\\/*\\/B\\/*
```

How can I modify to match above criteria.

Comment: Is the query format '_search?q=' necessary ？ Is elasticsearch query DSL (json) acceptable ？